# Obtaining HAR Request\Response C#

Tags: java, c#, selenium-webdriver, browsermob, browsermob-proxy

When launching browsermob on Windows through the supplied .bat file in a C# solution I am unable to retrieve the request\response data in the supplied HAR file from the REST API.

I have attempted setting the /proxy/[port]/har captureContent to true directly to the REST interface but it does not provide the request\response content.

Looking at the example code I see there is a setting supplied to the Java initialized object

```
// enable more detailed HAR capture, if desired (see CaptureType for the complete list)
proxy.enableHarCaptureTypes(CaptureType.REQUEST_CONTENT, CaptureType.RESPONSE_CONTENT);
```

I have begun writing some custom Java command line application code to provide these initialized settings, however I wanted to post to see if this is the correct path to obtaining the request\response content on the rest response.